# Как установить временные рамки для видео в tilda?

Tags: веб-дизайн, tilda

Я сделал сайт на Tilda и хочу ограничить видео по времени, чтобы видео начиналось в одно время, а закончилось в другое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде как нельзя так сделать штатными средствами

Comment: @mepihindeveloper Есть start sec и end sec . Но при установке временных рамок они не работают.

Comment: Ну если после чистки кеша все равно такое остается, то можно попробовать написать в поддержку им, так как может плагин отвалиться (в теории) с их стороны

Comment: Понял, спасибо!